# issues publishing jupyter extension with pip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm *developing* a simple Jupyter extension that only contains a JS file---https://github.com/yifanwu/notetaker/. Currently, it works if I clone the repo and then do `jupyter nbextension install`.

However, we wanted to streamline the process with pip, so I added https://github.com/yifanwu/notetaker/blob/master/setup.py

However, I realized two issues

1. We still need to run `jupyter nbextension install` it seems even after the pip install?
2. Running `jupyter nbextension install` bugs out with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notetaker'`

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually https://github.com/data-8/nbtimetravel  has a nice example set up.